# Sscanf with hexadecimal values

Tags: c++, scanf

I have to parser a char array in c++ that has hexadecimal values:

```
char test[20] = ":CF0100020003000400";
```

From test I have to obtain 0200 (512), 0300 (768) and 0400 (1024). I want to save these values in uint16_t type.

```
uint16_t value1;
uint16_t value2;
uint16_t value3;
sscanf(test, ":CF%*04x%04x%04x%04x", (int *)&value1, (int *)&value2, (int *)&value3);
```

I've obtain only the last value (value3 = 1024), but value1 and value2 are 0. However, if the variables are int, whitout the cast, the sscanf works fine. ¿How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your casting, and choice of the wrong format specifier causes undefined behaviour. Use the correct format specifiers according to the type of the variable:

```
std::sscanf(test, ":CF%04" SCNx16 "%04" SCNx16 "%04" SCNx16,
                      &value1,     &value2,     &value3);
```

Comment: I'm compiling in IAR and this solution give an error: expected a ")". I suppose that it is not recognizing the SCNx16 macros.

Comment: @user1799803 did you include the header where the macros are defined?

Comment: Yes, I've included it. Finally i've found that SCNx16 for my compiler is "h" so this line works: sscanf(test, ":CF%*04hx%04hx%04hx%04hx", &value1, &value2, &value3);

Comment: @user1799803 I suppose your standard library doesn't conform to C++11 then. Using `hx` should work as long as your program doesn't need to be ported to other systems.

Comment: @user1799803 : the compiler error "expected a ")" " might mean you accidentally put in a comma after the quote and before the SCNx16 macro (and your compiler was checking the validity of the scanf string against the following arguments).

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson no, this is not the problem. It is related with the sscanf definition and the SCNx16 macros. I've checked the syntax.